# laravel bootstrap- how to align properly in mobile layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I created a login page and it looks fine on a desktop screen(layout). It looks something like below:

[image]

However, when I start shrinking the screen to mobile layout, the words were gone and I thought bootstrap navbar takes care of the shrinking but the shrinking wrap those words in a `3 line box` and way below the screen.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- CSRF Token -->
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">


        <!-- Styles -->
        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <style>
            .backgroundImage {

                background-image: url(/images/homepage.jpg);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: 100%;




                width: 100%;

                height: auto;


            }

            @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
       nav{


       }
                }

        </style>

        {!! NoCaptcha::renderJs() !!}
    </head>

    <body class="backgroundImage">
        <div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light shadow-sm">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="navbar-brand " href="{{ url('/') }}">

                    </a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                        </ul>

                        <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
                            <!-- Authentication Links -->
                            @guest

                            @if (Route::has('login'))
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link " style="color:#f8f9fa; font-size:1.5rem;" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            @endif

                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" style="color:#f8f9fa; font-size:1.5rem;" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            @endif
                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" style="color:#f8f9fa; font-size:1.5rem;" href="{{ url('/registrations/dealer') }}">{{ __('Be a Dealer!') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            @endif

                            @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                        document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            @endguest
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <main class="py">

                @yield('content')
            </main>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Do I need to use `media query` to fix this? I am not very good with styling.

What do I need to add in to make it look natural?

Comment: Are you sure the links narrow/small enough to fit your mobile screen width remaining a single line?

Comment: @dajnz What do you mean?

Comment: If these your links (Login, register, ...) are too wide for your mobile screen size it is not way too keep them inline and fully visible obviously.

Comment: @dajnz I mean when I shrink them, they are encapsule in a `box` but how do I make the box position properly?

Answer (score 1):

Check [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/vmcujdhf/2/), I used your markup but tried to remove unnecessary visual noise. You can move screen splitter to expand/collapse the final page to see how it looks like. Yes, for this I've used a media query like this:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {
  #navbarSupportedContent {
    display: flex;
  }
  ul.navbar-nav {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  li.nav-item a.nav-link {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 5px;
  }
}
```

But on the other hand, this CSS snippet removes some styles added by bootstrap, so maybe this is not the best solution, and your issue can be handled with some capabilities of Bootstrap itself.

By the way, pay your attention that your links in your original markup have inline styles for font size right inside your tags, and this prevents external CSS style to change it (in this example I removed them).

Comment: I made a mistake, it's supposed to be the other page that displays properly. If I have 4 images display per row using `col-3` but when it shrinks to mobile layout, the images overlap. How do I make it display 2 items per row so it looks good?

Comment: Can you show your markup or create JSFiddle with it and share the link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60628668/laravel-bootstrap-how-to-use-media-query-to-align-two-items-per-row I posted it here. I think it's easier since it has picture. Sorry I am just bad at styling with media queries.

Comment: Ok, let me check it