# laravel bootstrap- how to use media query to align two items per row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a query page that displays a list of item for sale. It looks like below:[image]

[image]

It looks fine but when I changed to a smaller viewport or mobile layout, the items get stacked close to one another and it is out of alignment.

My code:

```
@section('content')


<style>
    .checked {
  color: orange;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

  .col-3{
    // some adjustment code to display 2 items per row on mobile
  }


</style>



<div>
    {{ Breadcrumbs::render('shop.category.subcategory', $category, $subcategory) }}


  <div class="container">
            <div class="row">        
              <div class="col-3">
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="btn btn-default round-background " type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <img src="{{asset('images/bedsheet.jpg')}}" style=" border-radius: 50%;  height: 150px; ">    
                  </button><hr>
                  <span class="text-capitalize"><strong>Bed Sheet</strong></span>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>  
              </div>  
              <div class="col-3">
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="btn btn-default round-background " type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <img src="{{asset('images/curtain.jpg')}}" style=" border-radius: 50%;  height: 150px;">    
                  </button><hr>
                  <span class="text-capitalize"> <strong>Curtain</strong> </span>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div> 
              </div>
              <div class="col-3">
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="btn btn-default round-background " type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <img src="{{asset('images/pink-bed-sheet.jpg')}}" style=" border-radius: 50%;  height: 150px;">    
                  </button><hr>
                  <span class="text-capitalize"> <strong>Curtain</strong> </span>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div> 
              </div>


              <div class="col-3">
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="btn btn-default round-background " type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <img src="{{asset('images/curtain.jpg')}}" style=" border-radius: 50%;  height: 150px;">    
                  </button><hr>
                  <span class="text-capitalize"> <strong>Curtain</strong> </span>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li><hr>
                    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div> 
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
            <!-- Options / Recommendation -->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 hidden-sm" style="border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 10px; right:33%; bottom: 220px; ">
                <!-- Related Categories -->
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">

                        <ul class="list-group">

                            @foreach ($allCategories as $relatedCategory)
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <a class="text-capitalize" style="font-weight: 520;" href="/shop/category/{{ $relatedCategory->slug }}">{{ $relatedCategory->name }}</a>

                                @if($relatedCategory->id == $category->id)
                                 <ul class="list-group">
                                    @foreach($category->subcategories as $childCategory)
                                    <li class="list-group-item">
                                         <a class="text-capitalize" style="font-weight: 490;" href="/shop/category/{{ $category->slug }}/{{ $childCategory->slug }}">{{ $childCategory->name }}</a> 
                                        @if($childCategory->id == $subcategory->id)
                                        <ul class="list-group">
                                            @foreach($subcategory->types as $childType)
                                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                                <a class="text-capitalize" style="font-weight: 400;" href="/shop/category/{{ $category->slug }}/{{ $childCategory->slug }}/{{ $childType->slug }}">{{ $childType->name }}</a>
                                            </li>
                                            @endforeach 
                                        </ul>
                                        @endif
                                    </li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul> <br>

                             @endif 
                            </li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul> <br>
                        <ul> 
                            <strong>PRICE</strong>
                               <li>Under RM25 </li> 
                               <li>RM 25 to RM 50 </li>
                               <li>RM50 to RM100 </li>
                               <li>RM100 to RM200 </li>
                               <li>RM200 & Above </li>

                               <input type="number" placeholder="Min" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="300">
                               <input type="number" placeholder="Max" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="300">
                               </ul> <br>

                               <ul>
                               <strong>COLOR</strong>
                               <li><input type="checkbox" id="white" name="white" value="white">
                                   <label for="white">WHITE</label>
                               </li><br>
                               <li><input type="checkbox" id="beige" name="beige" value="beige">
                                   <label for="beige">BEIGE</label>
                               </li><br>
                               <li><input type="checkbox" id="red" name="red" value="red">
                                   <label for="red">RED</label>
                               </li><br>
                               <li><input type="checkbox" id="maroon" name="maroon" value="maroon">
                                   <label for="beige">MAROON</label>
                               </li><br>
                               <li><input type="checkbox" id="grey" name="grey" value="grey">
                                   <label for="grey">GREY</label>
                               </li><br>
                               <li><input type="checkbox" id="black" name="black" value="black">
                                   <label for="black">BLACK</label>
                               </li><br>
                               </ul>

                               <ul>
                                  <strong>RATINGS</strong> 
                                  <li>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>

                               </li>
                               <li>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                          and up
                               </li>
                               <li>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star "></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                          and up
                               </li>
                               <li>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star "></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star "></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                          and up
                               </li>
                               <li>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star "></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star "></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star "></span>
                                   <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                          and up
                               </li>
                               </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>


            </div>



        </div>


    </div>
```

I figured I need to apply some CSS media to `col-3` but I do not know the exact way to adjust so it shows 2 items per row on a mobile layout. Is there a way to do this?

```
</div>

  @endsection
```

Comment: Try "col-6", it will fix your issue.

Comment: col-6 on all 4 items?

Comment: It doesn't really fix it because on desktop screen, it becomes 2 items per row now.

Comment: How much items you need on desktop?

Comment: Try to add these classes, "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6"

Comment: 4 items per row. If I start shrinking, it should be 2 items per row. Like normal e-commerce websites you see online

Comment: Yeah, i understand. Try the following classes

Comment: Could we use discussion chat? It's easier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209411/discussion-between-lord-jesus-and-gamers-agenda).

Answer (score 1):

Using `.col-6` and `.col-sm-3` will give 2 items per row on extra-small devices (<576px) and 4 items per row on any other device. If you wanted, for example, 3 items per row on small devices (576px-768px) you could use `.col-6`, `.col-sm-4`, and `.col-md-3`.

Take a look at the Bootstrap 4 for more information on this. You can find the Grid Layout documentation page at: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#all-breakpoints, and a list of the media queries Bootstrap uses at: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

Comment: But for the filter sidebar, how do you make it fit with the screen below the items?

Answer (score 1):

[This example](https://jsfiddle.net/fb01723o/2/) is likely will work for you. I used your original markup, removed some visual noise and added Bootstrap styles from CDN.

The changes are:

- `col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6` classes for your columns with images;
- removed hardcoded height inside inline styles for your images;
- addes some new styles below including media-query.

```css
div.dropdown button.btn-default.round-background img {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 90%;
}

div.dropdown button.btn-default.round-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 380px) {
  div.dropdown button.btn-default.round-background img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```